# Add stylesheets to rails static HTML page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, static, stylesheet, assets

I have a few static HTML pages in my rails project. They need access to stylesheets in my vendor assets folder. How can I add the proper references since they do not use the same application layout? I attempted adding a reference to the sheets directly in the vendor folder. This works during development but fails on deploy since the assets are compiled and the individual sheets no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

You should put all your HTML pages (static or not) in view folder if you want to use assets pipeline.
Don't forget that assets are dynamically generated, compressed and named so there is no way you can include them manually (without painful hacks).

Another solution is to put your stylesheets in /public folder together with your static HTML.

Comment: I have gone with the second option. Is there a special way to link to the stylesheets, or can i simply use the directory path.

Comment: in public folder you can treat them like real static pages, with relative or absolute paths, whatever pleases you :)